# SFML:Реализация перигелия и афелия

Tags: c++, sfml

Планета движется по закону:

```
x=Sun.x+radius.x*cos(time*speed);
y=Sun.y+radius.y*sin(time*speed);
```

Как реализовать ускорения при приближении до планеты и уменьшении скорости при отдалении? 
Спасибо!

Comment: У вас никакого афелия и перигелия нет, потому как орбита круговая...

Comment: @Harry радиусы разные. Правда, Солнце в центре, а не в фокусе.

Comment: @MBo А, да, не обратил внимания. Но. как вы верно заметили, фигня выходит. Дальше - для sashat. Если работать в полярной системе координат, то уравнение r=p/(1-e*coS(fi)), ну и учитывать, что r^2*fi'=const. Короче, простого вот такого решения нет, чтоб записать x и y в каждый момент времени - от многого зависит, и непросто зависит... Какая у вас сверхзадача? Просто картинка для красоты, или реальная модель?

Comment: реальная модель ну или приближённая к реальной.Я думаю что это можно как-то решить  зная расстояния от Солнца к планете.
Что такое p в вашей формуле?

Comment: Если реальная - я бы решал численно уравнения движения. Система из двух дифуравнений второго порядка, в принципе, ничего особо сложного..

Answer (score 1):

Решите численно уравнение Кеплера

```
2*Pi * t / T = E - e * sin(E)
```

где T - период, e - эксцентриситет

Т.е. в каждый период времени t нужно найти величину E (эксцентрическую аномалию), а из неё уже истинную аномалию v, что и даст положение планеты.

```
v = 2 * atan (tan(E/2) * Sqrt((1+e)/(1-e)))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Простая имитация разной скорости (с Солнцем в центре, а не в фокусе, как у автора) с использованием такого (Delphi) кода - приращение угла зависит от самого угла.

```
 cf := 1.0 / (2 + Cos(2 * an));
 an := an + speed * cf;
 x := cx + Round(rx * Cos(an));
 y := cy + Round(ry * Sin(an));
 Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
 Canvas.Ellipse(x - 10, y - 10, x + 11, y + 11);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105763/discussion-on-answer-by-mbo-sfml---).

Comment: У меня солнце в правом фокусе.

Comment: @sashat А по формуле из вопроса - в центре. Но не суть важно. Для фокуса не нужно удваивать аргумент косинуса

Comment: Не помогло.Планета ускоряется потом останавливаеться и движется в противоположном направлении

Comment: Ну Вы же видите результат работы реального кода (гифка коротковата, чуть больше оборота записал). Для того, чтобы максимальная скорость была справа, достаточно изменить знаменатель cf на`2 - Cos(an)`

Comment: у меня: position.x=center.x+radius.xcos(timespeed+speed*(1/(2-cos(speedtime)))); position.y=center.y+radius.ysin(timespeed+speed(1/(2-cos(speedtime))));